# Allow users to download files from subversion from a asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, svn

Is there a way to allow users to download large files from subversion using an asp.net web application. We don't want to give SVN accounts to all web users but want our site be able to serve the files from SVN without downloading the actual file to the server where web application is running. Is there a way this can be acheived?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ana

Answer (score 1):

You could foresee one SVN account and write an ASP.NET handler to process the file from the svn server into an in-memory file (DotSVN or something similar) and serve it to the user for download.

You might take a look at Mercurial Large Files Extension as well.

- [DotSVN](http://code.google.com/p/dotsvn/)
- [ASP.NET Handlers](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx)
- [Mercurial Large Files Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LargefilesExtension)

Comment: With in-memory file, if a large file is being downloaded or multiple requests come at the same time to download large file, won't I run out of memory?

Comment: depends on how large these files are and how much RAM is in the web server. If the files are huge, you could ask yourself if SVN is the way to go, anyway. There's always torrent or ftp.

Comment: Some files are pretty big close to a GB. The issue is, the files being downloaded are mostly releases (they are huge because they bundle lot of stuff), which are done frequently with no regular schedule and build group at where I work doesn't want to upload huge files twice, once in SVN and once in our web server, where the users login and download them. What Build group wants to do is upload it to SVN and the asp.net application to pull it directly from there. For this situation what do you suggest is good solution?

Comment: Edited answer. Take a look at Mercurial LFE.